# Removing optical sights from weapons

Tags: splinter-cell-conviction

It is possible to remove unlocked optical sights? They are very uncomfortable, no advantages, only narrow view.

If this is not possible, may be I can clear all game progress and start a new game without any unlocks?

Comment: I hope someone has an answer for this. It was a very poor design choice to not make the guns customizeable.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, though I would be interested to know if it were.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the only possible way is to remove all of your Conviction memory off of your xbox-360.

[Source](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/236338-Delete-ALL-splinter-cell-conviction-memory-Forums)

Comment: I'm PC gamer, btw

Comment: ok. then its a bit simpler, but worst. You would have to uninstall your game and remove all preferences.

Comment: You could just remove the saves without uninstalling. The saves are located in storage/2 inside Ubisoft's launcher directory.

Comment: He wasn't asking about the Xbox 360 version.